# Flipping a slice with a for loop logic error

Tags: go, slice

So I am trying to write a method that takes two slices, flips both of them and then gives them to each other.

Ex.

s1 = {1,2,3,4,5}

s2 = {6,7,8,9,10}

Should return:

s1 = {10,9,8,7,6}

s2 = {5,4,3,2,1}

Here is my code:

```
package main
import(
    "fmt"
)

func main(){
    f:= [5]int{1,2,3,4,5}
    h:= [5]int{6,7,8,9,10}
    var sliceF []int = f[0:5]
    var sliceH []int = h[0:5]

    fmt.Println(reverseReverse(sliceF,sliceH))

}
func reverseReverse(first []int, second []int) ([]int, []int){
    //creating temp arrays to hold the traversed arrays before swapping.
    var tempArr1 []int = first
    var tempArr2 []int = second
    //count is used for counting up the tempArrays in the correct order in the For loops
    var count  int= 0
    //goes through the first array and sets the values starting from the end equal to the temp array
    //which increases normally from left to right.
    for i :=len(first)-1; i>=0;i--{
        tempArr1[count] = first[i]
        fmt.Println(i)
        count++
    }
    count =0
    //same as first for loop just on the second array
    for i :=len(second)-1; i>=0;i--{
        tempArr2[count] = second[i]
        count++
    }
    //trying to replace the values of the param arrays to be equal to the temp arrays
    first=tempArr2
    second = tempArr1
    //returning the arrays
    return first,second
}
```

When run here is the output:

4

3

2

1

0

[10 9 8 9 10]

[5 4 3 4 5]

*Not I included a print statement in the for loop to check if the index is decreasing properly.

I understand there are better ways to do this but for proof of concept I want to use a for loop.

Any help appreciated.  I am new to go and tend to have java habits so I assume somehow my problem is related to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done much simpler by realizing there's no need to actually swap the individual elements. Instead, reverse each array and swap their order. Much simpler!

```
func reverseReverse( a, b []int ) ([]int, []int) {
    return reverse(b), reverse(a)
}

func reverse( a []int ) []int {
    end := len(a) - 1

    // Allocate a new array slice of the same length to copy to.
    ret := make( []int, len(a) )

    // Copy each element of a into ret, reversed.
    for i := range a {
        ret[end-i] = a[i]
    }

    return ret
}
```

With that revelation, there's little need for the very specialized `reverseReverse` function. Swap the order yourself.

```
fmt.Println(reverse(sliceH), reverse(sliceF))
```

---

Note that if you just want to take a slice of an array, it's sufficient to write `sliceH []int := h[:]` without specifying the start and end. The start is assumed to be 0 and the end is the end. Also note there's no need to declare the type, `:=` takes care of that for you.

Even better, you can declare and initialize them directly.

```
sliceF:= []int{1,2,3,4,5}
sliceH:= []int{6,7,8,9,10}
```

Comment: Got it fixed thanks for your Help!  I needed to give the slice a length and didn't know how till I saw your make method and looked it up!

Comment: If you don't mind reversing in-place, it can be even shorter by using the multiple-variable-assignment syntax.  Cuts down on memory footprint, too. https://play.golang.org/p/cCXEuQ3Nr5

Comment: @Kaedys Yes, peterSO's answer demonstrates reversing in place. With a good array duplication function, the inplace version would be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**

`tempArr1[count] = first[i]`

This line is logically identical to:

`first[count] = first[i]`

**Detailed answer:**

`x := [5]int{}` and `x := []int{}` are in fact two very different assignments. In the first case `x` is actually a static array. In the second case `x` is a **slice** which is in fact **a data structure which has a length, capacity and a pointer to the underlying array**. Therefore, `var tempArr1 []int = first` means copy the pointer to the underlying array of `first` into the `tempArr1`, so any modification to `first[i]` will be reflected in `tempArr1` and vice versa

Comment: Ahhh ok, so then to fix that I would drop the equals sign portion and just declare it?

Comment: But the problem I run into is I want it to be that I don't know the size of the slice coming in.  So when I drop the = first part what do I replace it with, because when I just drop it I get a array out of bounds exception.

Answer (score 1):

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func reverse(s []int) []int {
    for i := 0; i < len(s)/2; i++ {
        s[i], s[len(s)-1-i] = s[len(s)-1-i], s[i]
    }
    return s
}

func main() {
    s1, s2 := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, []int{6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
    fmt.Println(s1, s2)
    s1, s2 = reverse(s2), reverse(s1)
    fmt.Println(s1, s2)
}
```

Output:

```
[1 2 3 4 5] [6 7 8 9 10]
[10 9 8 7 6] [5 4 3 2 1]
```

Comment: Note that although `reverse()` returns a slice, as if it were a copy, it reverses the original array. That's misleading. `reverse(s1); reverse(s2); fmt.Println(s2, s1)` works just as well.